# How to migrate hugo site from localhost to Linux server

Tags: hugo

I am new in Hugo and I already created the home page ready with prebuild theme which I found on https://github.com/giraffeacademy/ga-hugo-theme but now I want to make it live on my Hostgator server so what I did after override my theme I run the command

from `hugo server -D to hugo`

then I see the public folder and I just used that and make it live here

http://webdemoapp.com/Bravocore/

my question is: Is this the right way to make it live? or have to install the hugo server on hostgator?

Note:I have window10 where I am working with hugo server

Answer (score 1):

TLDR: Using just **hugo** is the right way. Source: [Hugo Docs](https://gohugo.io/getting-started/usage/#deploy-your-website)

The **hugo server** command is normally used for debugging purposes. To build the page itself use just **hugo** as command and it will generate the content within the public/ folder. You can then just upload everything to your hoster. There it should be distributed through e.g a [Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/) or [Nginx](https://nginx.org/en/) webserver. Those are mostly preinstalled.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, you should run hugo and hugo server only on your local machine where you also write the content for your website. When you run hugo, it will generate static HTML, CSS and JS which you should then upload to an appropriate webhoster or other server.

The whole point of static site generators is not having to run much or any specific backend stuff on the server to render the content of your website.

Answer (score 0):

U don't need to install Hugo on ur server. Build the Hugo site by running Hugo and then the build will create a set of files which will be basic HTML pages, Upload the files to the server. The server can serve these Html pages.

U can run a Hugo site without a server bu using Netlify, Upload your code to Git repo and link the repo to Netlify then deploy your site.

Answer (score 0):

Update to Vishnu Prasad sir's answer. Recently I deployed a Hugo site to shared Linux server. Before running the hugo command, update the URL of the site in baseURL of the config file. Zip the entire public folder. Upload to the server folder, and extract. The Website works are expected.